# How to fix SOAP - UpdateList NetSuite Error: Record has been changed

Tags: web-services, soap, integration, netsuite, mulesoft

I am trying to find solution when integration uses "updatelist" to update 5 fields on sales order lines. The issue comes when we have more than 5 lines on sales order. We are sending multiple "UpdateList" SOAP request for same sales order at the same time.

See the screenshot of SOAP logs below. Some of the lines failed to update due to error :
platformCore:codeRCRD_HAS_BEEN_CHANGED</platformCore:code>

platformCore:messageRecord has been changed</platformCore:message>

How do i resolve this? send updatelist request and wait for it to finish for same salesorder?

[image]

Error Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please use text instead of images. Do not use screenshots for text, logs, errors (unless graphical only), code or Mule flows/configurations. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Comment: Why did you add the mulesoft tag? Kindly provide some context on why is that relevant to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "Record has been changed" error when changing a Sales Orders status to Pending Fulfilment using Suitescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446067/getting-record-has-been-changed-error-when-changing-a-sales-orders-status-to-p)

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question.

> We are sending multiple "UpdateList" SOAP request for same sales order at the same time.

A record is locked when it's updated and is the cause of your error. The only way to avoid this error is to do the updates either when the record isn't locked or simply perform a single update with all the information instead of making multiple updates to the same record.